# How to pass parameter to Form Submit handler in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to identify the user who submits the **FormResponse** so that next time he asks for the form I can redirect him to **edit link** with his prev answers. In https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events the handler is described. But I see no way how to pass parameter from **prefilled form** (with id of a user as prefilled parameter) to **submit handler**. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: you can't identitfy the user and on purpose so. Many commercial users would like that: answer a very simple question and your identity is known...
Identified submission is possible in Google Apps for Business, but only within the company's domain.

Comment: How identified? Can you pass the link to docs? I can't find that

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, this is intentional but there is an alternative that does not use Google Forms:  you can use UiApp service or HTMLServiceto build a webapp working as a form that will ask the users to authorize access to their email identity.

Not so simple for sure but actually the only possible alternative.

Comment: I don't need their email. I pass them to form through my **servlet** and I can prepopulate form with my **internal user's id**. So when they try to edit their answer through my portal I redirect them to saved **edit URL**. And I need to save that **edit URL** when user first time submits. Unfortunatly UiApp is not an option. It's easier to make my own service that will generate forms from JSON in that case

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could publish a script as a webpage and get an alternative live link.  That link would check the current user against a user field in the form.  If they exist then it would redirect to the edit entry, if they don't exist it will redirect to the form submission form.